# Proper way to deal with lists and map

Tags: list-manipulation

So, I wanted to do something that I assumed would be really simple. Given two lists, $A = \{a_1, a_2, ...\}, B = \{ ... \}$, I wanted to take a function $f(a, b)$ and generate a list with $\{ f(a_1, b_1), f(a_1, b_2), ... \}$, i.e. just the cartesian product.

Of course, it's really easy, in principal, to do this:

```
f[#1, #2] & @@@ Outer[List, {a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2}]
```

The annoyance comes in when the elements are themselves lists. In this case, everything breaks. Ridiculous things start happening.

There is a "trivial" solution; just use dummy variables in the above statement, and replace it in with what I want later. But to me this seems fundamentally wrong somehow. Surely it should be possible to work with lists of arbitrary type; and not have to "protect" your mapping functions from lists of lists.

Any thoughts? Am I missing some fundamental strategy here?

-- Edit:

To elaborate more, I'm actually trying to make the following work:

```
dim = 2; (* Say *)
Table[
  SomeFunc[dim, g, op, #] & /@ 
    Subsets[Range[dim], {i}], {i, 1, dim}
]
```

`op` previously was a single matrix; but now I need it to be a list of matricies. That is so say, I want to run "SomeFunc" for each matrix in that list, and also each of the results that come from the `Subset` function (note, of course, that `Subsets` returns lists.)

Comment: You should be doing something like `Outer[f, {a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2}]`. You will also want to look into the documentation for `Outer[]`; in particular, its support of level arguments.

Comment: Okay, so I actually need to evaluate `f(x, y, a, b)`. So I don't think `Outer` will work in that case. Well, maybe I could make it work ... but I think this question still is relevant.

Comment: I specifically discussed this issue [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node502.html)

Comment: Could you maybe talk about your *actual* problem that is requiring you to do that sort of construction?

Comment: @J.M. Done. @Leonid; thanks, seems to be the same recommendation as J.M.; I'm not sure `Distribute` is appropriate in this case, but nice to know about.

Comment: I suppose something like `Outer[SomeFunc[dim, g, #1, #2] &, opList, subList, 1]`, then?

Comment: Yes ... you appear to be right. Thanks! I guess I was inappropriately using Map/Apply!

Comment: (Note that I had to actually add a `Flatten` in after the Outer to get exactly the same functionality.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To resolve this question:

This construction would do what you want, it seems:

```
opList = Array[C, {3, 2, 2}]; (* list of matrices *)
sList = Array[K, {3, 4}]; (* list of vectors *)

Outer[f, opList, sList, 1]
   {{f[{{C[1, 1, 1], C[1, 1, 2]}, {C[1, 2, 1], C[1, 2, 2]}},
       {K[1, 1], K[1, 2], K[1, 3], K[1, 4]}], 
     f[{{C[1, 1, 1], C[1, 1, 2]}, {C[1, 2, 1], C[1, 2, 2]}},
       {K[2, 1], K[2, 2], K[2, 3], K[2, 4]}], 
     f[{{C[1, 1, 1], C[1, 1, 2]}, {C[1, 2, 1], C[1, 2, 2]}},
       {K[3, 1], K[3, 2], K[3, 3], K[3, 4]}]},
    {f[{{C[2, 1, 1], C[2, 1, 2]}, {C[2, 2, 1], C[2, 2, 2]}},
       {K[1, 1], K[1, 2], K[1, 3], K[1, 4]}], 
     f[{{C[2, 1, 1], C[2, 1, 2]}, {C[2, 2, 1], C[2, 2, 2]}},
       {K[2, 1], K[2, 2], K[2, 3], K[2, 4]}], 
     f[{{C[2, 1, 1], C[2, 1, 2]}, {C[2, 2, 1], C[2, 2, 2]}},
       {K[3, 1], K[3, 2], K[3, 3], K[3, 4]}]},
    {f[{{C[3, 1, 1], C[3, 1, 2]}, {C[3, 2, 1], C[3, 2, 2]}},
       {K[1, 1], K[1, 2], K[1, 3], K[1, 4]}], 
     f[{{C[3, 1, 1], C[3, 1, 2]}, {C[3, 2, 1], C[3, 2, 2]}},
       {K[2, 1], K[2, 2], K[2, 3], K[2, 4]}], 
     f[{{C[3, 1, 1], C[3, 1, 2]}, {C[3, 2, 1], C[3, 2, 2]}},
       {K[3, 1], K[3, 2], K[3, 3], K[3, 4]}]}}
```

The level argument `1` in `Outer[]` essentially tells `Outer[]` to treat everything in level `1` (that is, the elements of the input lists) as atomic, instead of having `Outer[]` treat the first list as a rank-3 tensor and the second list as a matrix.

Comment: Almost; I had to add an extra `Flatten` in front of the Outer; but this definitely was the right idea - I didn't know about using pure functions in like this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you are after ?

```
a = {a1, a2, a3}
b = {b1, b2, b3}

Distribute[f[a, b], List]
```

> {f[a1, b1], f[a1, b2], f[a1, b3], f[a2, b1], f[a2, b2], f[a2, b3], 
>    f[a3, b1], f[a3, b2], f[a3, b3]}

And as suggested by Artes the equivalence of solutions can be shown by:

```
a = Array[c, {3, 2, 2}]; b = Array[k, {3, 4}]; 
Distribute[f[a, b], List] === Flatten[Outer[f, a, b, 1], 1]
```

> True

Comment: Nice solution +1, one can add e.g. for `a = Array[c, {3, 2, 2}]; b = Array[k, {3, 4}];` then `Distribute[f[a, b], List] === Flatten[Outer[f, a, b, 1], 1]` yields `True`.

Comment: @Artes, thank you.